# Winedt cannot output pdf after inserting image

Tags: graphics, winedt

I can generate a pdf without inserting image, but after inserting a eps image, the preview button turns gray and I cannot find the pdf.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Probably you compile with `pdflatex`, which cannot handle .eps files. Two solution: either you use the chain: `latex -->dvips -->ps2pdf` or you converts the `.eps` file to `.pdf`, for instance with `epspdf` (with option `tight bounding box`).